# Resolve field returns null for all fields except ID (extended type)

Tags: graphql, nestjs

I have original GQL type from `intermediaries` microservice.

```
@ObjectType('Intermediary')
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export class IntermediaryType implements Intermediary {
    @Field(() => ID)
    id: string

    @Field()
    beneficiaryName: string

    // and other fields
}
```

And another GQL type that extends from external GQL type.

```
@ObjectType('Intermediary')
@Directive('@extends')
@Directive('@key(fields: "id")')
export class IntermediaryType {
    @Field(() => ID)
    @Directive('@external')
    id: string
}
```

GQL type that nests external GQL type:

```
@ObjectType('FXPayment')
export class FXPaymentType {
    @Field(() => ID)
    id: string

    @Field(() => [IntermediaryType])
    intermediaries?: IntermediaryType[]

    // and other fields
}
```

And I have a resolver for my mutation and `intermediaries` field.

```
@Resolver(() => FXPaymentType)
export class FXPaymentsResolver {
    constructor(private _fxPaymentsService: FXPaymentsService) {}

    @Mutation(() => FXPaymentType)
    async createFXPayment(
        @Args('input') input: CreateFXPaymentInput,
    ): Promise<FXPaymentType> {
        const createdFXPayment = await this._fxPaymentsService.createFXPayment(input)

        return createdFXPayment
    }

    @ResolveField()
    intermediaries(@Parent() fxPayment: FXPaymentEntity): IntermediaryType[] {
        const usedIntermediaries = [
            fxPayment.nostroRequisites,
            fxPayment.providerRequisites,
            fxPayment.orderingRequisites,
        ]

        return usedIntermediaries
    }
}
```

The problem is that when mutation executed -- nested `IntermediaryType` contains only `id` field whereas other fields are nullable. I logged data in `@ResolveField()` and it showed me that all fields are not in null. I tried to remove `@ResolveField` and allow high-level resolver to resolve `intermediaries` field automatically (that is I just created `intermediaries` in my mutation) -- it doesn't work.

But still, I **do** really don't know what I'm doing wrong... Any attempts to forcely assign value to these fields failed also. Could you give any helpful comments on that? What should I try to do? Is everything okay with my code or not? Any ideas? Please, help.

Comment: I have the same problem. If you found a solution I would like to know

Comment: @klaas0 you have to define @ResolveReference() for shared gql type. See https://docs.nestjs.com/graphql/federation#code-first

Comment: I have added an @ResolveReference() for the 2 resolvers in the different services. But It's still not working. all properties null except id

Comment: @klaas0 In fact you should add only 1 @ResolveReference() in the service where your original GQL type is defined. And you should return the whole object by id. In the 2nd service you should return an object containing id field for the field you want. Please, could you share me with your code? Maybe I can help you

Comment: You were right, i needed to delete one of my resolvers.
Also my types weren't completely right, this was the main reason why it didn't work.
Thanks for helping me!